# What are the math Prerequisite for understanding 'First Order Motion Model for Image Animation' Paper?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mathematics, generative-models

[This](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/31c0b36aef265d9221af80872ceb62f9-Paper.pdf) is the 'First Order Motion Model for Image Animation' Paper. But I don't understand most of the mathematical things in the paper. What are the math Prerequisite for understanding this paper?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical analysis, more specifically spaces, differentiation and analytics functions (Taylor series, etc).
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis

Maths of neural networks is a plus.